# Mongodb Date Comparison with $gte and $lte

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need a query that helps me to find results with date filder
below is my model

```
loads: [
    startdate: {

        type: Date

    },
    enddate: {

        type: Date

    }
]
```

below is data in my model

```
{
    _id: "fefee24242ref3t231ffg2",
    loads: {
        startdate: "2021-07-05T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        enddate: "2021-07-22T00:00:00.000+00:00"
    }

},
{
    _id: "fefee24242ref3t231ffg2",
    loads: {
        startdate: "2021-07-06T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        enddate: "2021-07-22T00:00:00.000+00:00"
    }

}
```

I tried the below command but I return only one document. I don't why this happen

```
db.collection.find({}{loads: {

    $elemMatch: {
        $and: [
           {
                startdate: {$lte: new Date()
           },
           {
                enddate: {$gte: new Date()
           },
        ]
     }

}})
```

I want all collections in which the start date less than the current date and end date greater than current date

but I get only single collection

Comment: `$elemMatch` is used for arrays, skip it - there is no array in your document.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.now()` returns a number.

You should use `new Date()`. This returns an `ISODate`.

Comment: Yes i tried also this but again no change

Comment: Ohh. That's interesting. i just ran some query with local data to check and it worked. Can you double check if your data has values which satisfy the constraint

Comment: i checked my data
please try to put same data and you get one single document

Comment: kindly check the updated question. i just changed it. i received only single one document

Comment: As @wernfried-domscheit mentioned, there's no need to have `$elemMatch`. Your model specifies an array inside **loads** but your data has JSON in **loads**